# Firmar APK con Google Play App Signing

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-developers-console

quería subir mi apk de Android al **Play Store**, por desgracia le di al botoncito de registrar en Google App Signing. 
El caso es que ahora cuando intento subir mi aplicación me dice que las claves no coinciden. 
Cuando voy al apartado de **Google Play App Signing**, ellos te dan el certificado de firma de aplicaciones con 3 huellas digitales, i el certificado de subida con otras 3 huellas digitales. 
[image: No se si hacia falta tachar, pero por si acaso..]

Estos certificados se pueden descargar, te los dan en formato “.pem”, ahí el problema. Cuando intento pasar el certificado a mi keystore, me dice que el certificado es un “Trusted certificate”, yo necesito la private key para poder firmar. 
Estoy firmando la aplicación desde **Android Studio**.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que has perdido la key y quieres poder recuperarla? ¿Ya subiste alguna versión de la app desde Android Studio?

Comment: No, no tengo ninguna key, solo las publicas (no se si el certificado .pem contiene las private), en todo caso si las contiene nose como obtenerlas.
Las apps las puedo subir como versiones de debug, pero no firmadas, ya que me pide que la key coincida..

Comment: Yo la verdad que desconocía el Google Play App Signing y siempre he utilizado keys para subir las aplicaciones que he puesto yo a mano desde el Android Studio (he generado yo el fichero .jks desde el propio Android Studio). Luego una vez que quieras subir una nueva versión siempre necesitarás importar ese fichero .jks para poder subir una nueva versión de tu .apk al market. Haciéndolo de esta manera si que se que hay una manera de recuperar la key si la pierdes, pero la verdad que desconozco como funciona el Google Play App Signing.

Comment: La idea era esa, pero me hacia gracia probarlo, y ahora me doy cuenta de que no hay vuelta atrás, no se puede anular la suscripción y la información por parte de Google es realmente pésima.. me sorprende.

Comment: ¿Tenías alguna versión anterior ya subida al market? Si no, como lo que comprueban creo que es el nombre del paquete siempre puedes modificar un poco el nombre del paquete desde tu proyecto y generar el fichero .jks para subir tu primera versión y sucesivas. Aunque ten mucho cuidado de no perder el fichero .jks o tampoco podrás subir más versiones. Sí, la verdad que la desinformación de Google es increíble en este sentido.

Comment: Firmada no, solo tengo subida una debug_apk

Comment: Entonces otra opción que se me ocurre es que borres la versión de debug del market y crees una para publicar desde Android Studio con su correspondiente fichero .jks. Yo creo que así te tendría que funcionar incluso con el mismo nombre de paquete.

Comment: Me sale esto... Has subido un APK que no está firmado con el certificado de subida. Debes utilizar el mismo certificado. El certificado de subida tiene la siguiente huella digital:
[ SHA1: numeros i letras.. ]
. Sin embargo, el certificado utilizado para firmar el APK que has subido tiene la siguiente huella digital:
[ SHA1: numeros i letras.. ]

Comment: ¿Osea te reconoce todo el rato el del Google Play App Signing?

Comment: Exacto vv' no hay manera, he enviado un correo a google a ver si hay suerte y me ayudan un poco

Comment: Por favor, si te dan una solución publicala y marcala como aceptada. Yo estaré al tanto mientras para ver si hay novedades.

Comment: Si, ningún problema. Muchas gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Otro aqui que no sabia como funciona ese sistema, leyendo la documentacion veo que basta con firmar el .apk con el .jks. Ir a gestion de versiones >> version de la aplicacion. Ahi junto a "Google Play App Signing" hay un boton Aceptar. Y automaticamente Google quita la firma que pusiste y la firma con la que ellos almacenan. Pero si dices que eso no funciona... No obstante dejo el link por si alguien quiere echarle un ojo. https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=es

Comment: buenas lo que indicas en esos pasos lo hacia y funcionaba, pero el sabado 09/02/2019 actualice mi android studio, y ahora cuando genero mi apk, y lo subo me dice que Tu Android App Bundle está firmado con una clave no válida. Asegúrate de que contenga la clave de firma correcta y vuelve a intentarlo. Llevo desde el sabado haciendo el mismo proceso que hacia para subir mis actualizaciones y ahora no me deja

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución es la siguiente:

Primero: Subir la APK con una firma que tu mismo puedas generar (Con los datos que tu desees colocar desde el Android Studio, y pones de contraseña del **Key Password** la Huella digital en formato MD5 de la seccion "Certificado de firma de apps".

Segundo: Subes la APK a GOOGLE PLAY

Tercero: Genera la APK, pero con un numero de version de codigo diferente (esto se modifica desde los archivos fuentes de tu APP (En mi caso fue el archivo: AndroidManifest.xml). Debes firmar la APK con el mismo JKS del apk que subiste inicialmente.

Cuarto: Subes la APK a GOOGLE PLAY.

Explicacion: Google Play App Signing ha utilizado una verificacion de 2 pasos para publicar las APK. Pero, debes seguir utilizando el mismo JKS. (no tomes en cuenta los certificados que te ofrecen para descargar, esos certificados solo representan los datos que subiste de la PRIMERA APK firmada).

Comment: Y en este nuevo proceso, el fichero ".pepk" generado a partir del .jks cuando activas la opcion "Export Encrypted Key for enrolling published app in Google Play App Signing" es necesario utilizarlo en este proceso?